# Windows Server AppFabric Cache and Database synchronization

Tags: .net, appfabric, azure-appfabric, appfabric-beta-2, appfabric-cache

We are planning to use Windows Server AppFabric Caching for a healthcare application.
We have a Patient master and other master data which we want to cache using AppFabric Cache.
However we also have backend integrations setup with other applications using SQL Server Service Broker and Replication which can update this Patient master and other lookup data. How can we notify AppFabric Cache when this data is updated using Service Broker, so that cache always reflects the latest Patient master and other master data information. Can we use SQL CacheDependency or SQL Server Notification services?

Thanks,
Gaurav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with Appfabric because it is limited in dependency features and I believe it has no mechanism to synchronize with the DB and it is up to the client application to reload the fresh data from the DB. A caching solution that could be benificial for you is NCache, which has a complete set of dependency features and synchonization options without the client application being involved. Please visit

www.alachisoft.com/NCache